# Intellij java extends not working/ not finding the superclass

Tags: java, intellij-idea, extends, intellij-14

I am attempting to use the extends for a super class, but I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. I have tried to do extends and another class and that works if it is one of java's classes but none of my own. I have included a screen shot of what I have. Thank you for your time. The error that I get is "Can't resolve symbol"

---

[Intelli J screen capture of what I am attempting to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDcUO.jpg)

Comment: Please, don't post screenshots, post the code itself, and post full error message as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

first of all you programing in the default package, which isn't a good practice, second of all your javaclasses are outside your sourcefolder and finally I don't see any inports.

Answer (score -1):

Your HashTableChaining class is not underneath the source root folder - "src". Intellij doesn't know how to resolve it because it's not in your sources.

You should move those *.java files into your src folder and it will work.